# Combine features in Sklearn Pipeline

Tags: python, scikit-learn

I would like to use a pipeline including a `TfidfVectorizer` and a `SVC`. However, in between, I would like to concatenate some features extracted from non-textual data to the output of the `TfidfVectorizer`.

I have tried creating a custom class (approach based on this [tutorial](https://fizzylogic.nl/2017/11/07/learn-how-to-build-flexible-machine-learning-pipelines-in-sklearn/)) to do this but this does not seem to work.

Here is what I have tried so far:

```
pipeline = Pipeline([
    ('tfidf', TfidfVectorizer()),
    ('transformer', CustomTransformer(one_hot_feats)),
    ('clf', MultinomialNB()),
])

parameters = {
    'tfidf__min_df': (5, 10, 15, 20, 25, 30),
    'tfidf__max_df': (0.8, 0.9, 1.0),
    'tfidf__ngram_range': ((1, 1), (1, 2)),
    'tfidf__norm': ('l1', 'l2'),
    'clf__alpha': np.linspace(0.1, 1.5, 15),
    'clf__fit_prior': [True, False],
}

grid_search = GridSearchCV(pipeline, parameters, cv=5, n_jobs=-1, verbose=1)
grid_search.fit(df["short description"], labels)
```

Here is the `CustomTransformer` class

```
class CustomTransformer(TransformerMixin):
"""Class that concatenates the one hot encode category feature with the tfidf data."""

def __init__(self, one_hot_features):
    """Initializes an instance of our custom transformer."""
    self.one_hot_features = one_hot_features

def fit(self, X, y=None, **kwargs):
    """Dummy fit function that does nothing particular."""

    return self

def transform(self, X, y=None, **kwargs):
    """Adds our external features"""
    return numpy.hstack((one_hot_feats, X))
```

This approach works as long as X does not change dimensions inside the custom class (probably a limitation related to the TransformerMixin), however, in my case, I will have additional features appended to my data. Should my custom class inherit from a different base class or is there a different approach to solve this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can combine multiple features using Sklearn's [**FeatureUnion**](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.pipeline.FeatureUnion.html), and transform specific columns using **[ColumnTransformer](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.compose.ColumnTransformer.html)**:

from **docs**:

> **FeatureUnion**
>
> Concatenates results of multiple transformer objects.
>
> This estimator applies a list of transformer objects in parallel to
> the input data, then concatenates the results. This is useful to
> combine several feature extraction mechanisms into a single
> transformer.
>
> **ColumnTransformer**
>
> Applies transformers to columns of an array or pandas DataFrame.
>
> This estimator allows different columns or column subsets of the input
> to be transformed separately and the features generated by each
> transformer will be concatenated to form a single feature space. This
> is useful for heterogeneous or columnar data, to combine several
> feature extraction mechanisms or transformations into a single
> transformer.

In your case you can do that using [**make_column_transformer**](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.compose.make_column_transformer.html)

```
from sklearn.compose import make_column_transformer
pipeline = Pipeline([
    ('transformer',  make_column_transformer((TfidfVectorizer(), ['text_column']),
                                             (OneHotEncoder(), ['categorical_column']),)),
    ('clf', MultinomialNB()),
])
```

**EDIT:**

set `remainder` to `'passthrough'` in [**make_column_transformer**](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.compose.make_column_transformer.html) so all remaining columns that were not specified in transformers will be automatically passed through.